# Is react-native-ui-lib available for React Native 0.60 ? (ANDROID X)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, androidx

I am newbie with react-native,

but i would like to know when **react-native-ui-lib** will be compatible with react-native **0.60 >**

**(I currently use react-native 0.60.4)**

https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib

I really like this framework, it is so useful.

I have used it in older versions of react native but i think that it won't work because Android X had made a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it seems impossible to use at the moment. The version supported by the document is specified in `0.57`. I think the solution would be to leave this part in Isue and check the schedule.

There's something on [this link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib/issues/464) that you want.

[image: support]